# Why subset cannot be called in a wrapper function using lapply

Tags: r

`subset_base` is a simple form of base r's `subset()` function. The example is taken from Advanced R Chapter 20.6.1.

This function for itself works fine:

```r
subset_base <- function(data, rows) {
  rows <- substitute(rows)
  rows_val <- eval(rows, data, parent.frame())
  data[rows_val, , drop = FALSE]
}

my_df <- data.frame(x = 1:3)
  
subset_base(my_df, x == 1)
#>   x
#> 1 1
```

However, when we build a wrapper function `apply_subset`, define some value `zzz` in this wrapper function and call (in the same function) `lapply()` on `subset_base` supplying `zzz` as argument it can't be found.

I want to better understand why `zzz` can't be found. My mental model was the following:  `subset_base` is called by `lapply` which is called by `apply_subset`. Within `subset_base` we evaluate the `rows` argument in the supplied `data.frame` `data` which is automatically converted to an environment. This environment is encapsulated by the calling environment `parent.frame()`. Which should be the execution environment of `lapply`. I thought that this environment has again the calling environment of `lapply` as its parent. This would be the execution environment of `apply_subset`. But this doesn't seem to be the case, since if this would be true, `zzz` should be found.

```r
apply_subset <- function(){
  zzz <- 2
  dfs <- list(data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 4:6))
  lapply(dfs, FUN = subset_base, x == zzz)
}

apply_subset()
#> Error in eval(rows, data, parent.frame()): object 'zzz' not found
```

Even stranger, when we change to call to `lapply` from supplying `subset_base` directly as an object / function name, and instead wrap it into an anonymous function, `zzz` can be found.

```r
apply_subset2 <- function(){
  zzz <- 2
  dfs <- list(data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 4:6))
  lapply(dfs, FUN = \(df) subset_base(df, x == zzz))
}

apply_subset2()
#> [[1]]
#>   x
#> 2 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] x
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would highly appreciate an explanation of (1) what the parent environments of each execution environment in the call stack are, (2) why my assumption that they align is, apparently, wrong, and (3) why this changes, when the call to `lapply` uses an anonymous function. Further it would be great to know, if (4) there is any way to make the call to lapply work without using an anonymous function (Advanced R seems to suggest that the (maybe) only solution is to use rlangs quosures).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key point is that if we evaluate an expression with respect to the parent frame it will look through one level of the call stack and if not found will not look further through the call stack but will look through the environment in which the caller was *defined* and recursively through its ancestors.

With this background we can answer the questions:

*(1) what the parent environments of each execution environment in the call stack are,*

When `apply_subset` is run the function `subset_base` is passed to `lapply` and then the code inside `lapply` invokes the passed `subset_base` so the execution environment inside `lapply` is the parent frame  to `subset_base` and not the execution environment inside `apply_subset` where `zzz` resides.  `zzz` is not in the execution envionrment of `lapply` so the next place it looks is the parent environment of `lapply` where `lapply` was *defined* (not further up the call stack).  In this case it looks in the base package but `zzz` is not there either and then it looks through the global environment and all packages on the search path but `zzz` is not there hence the error.

*(2) why my assumption that they align is, apparently, wrong, and*

See above.

*(3) why this changes, when the call to lapply uses an anonymous function. Further it would be great to know, if*

When the anonymous function invokes `subset_base` it looks for `zzz` in the anonymous function's execution environment but since it is not there it looks to the parent environment of the anonymous function (not further up the call stack) and since the anonymous function was defined in `apply_subset` the parent environment is the execution environment of `apply_subset` where `zzz` is found.

*(4) there is any way to make the call to lapply work without using an anonymous function*

The way to do this which generalizes to other situations is to pass around the environment by having an explicit `envir=` argument like this:

```
subset_base <- function(data, rows, envir = parent.frame()) {   ##
  rows <- substitute(rows)
  rows_val <- eval(rows, data, envir)  ##
  data[rows_val, , drop = FALSE]
}

apply_subset <- function(){
  zzz <- 2
  dfs <- list(data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 4:6))
  lapply(dfs, FUN = subset_base, x == zzz, envir = environment()) ##
}

apply_subset()
```

giving

```
[[1]]
  x
2 2

[[2]]
[1] x
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying answer. So my mistake was in assuming that evaluating in the parent frame will look up all the call stack. But as you write, that is not the case. "it will look through one level of the call stack and if not found will not look further through the call stack but will look through the environment in which the caller was defined and recursively through its ancestors."

Answer (score 2):

For the last (unnumbered) "way to make the call to lapply work", here's a kludge:

```r
subset_base <- function(data, rows, .rows = substitute(rows)) {
  rows_val <- eval(.rows, data, parent.frame())
  data[rows_val, , drop = FALSE]
}
subset_base(my_df, x == 1)
#   x
# 1 1

apply_subset <- function(){
  zzz <- 2
  dfs <- list(data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 4:6))
  lapply(dfs, FUN = subset_base, .rows = substitute(x == zzz))
}
apply_subset()
# [[1]]
#   x
# 2 2
# [[2]]
# [1] x
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The intent of the `.rows` arg is that for interactive use, `subset_base` works file, whereas programmatic use should know about using the `.rows` argument. I'm not really satisfied with this, admittedly, it feels more kludgy than I typically like to provide ... but I'll post it to start some more conversation.

Not sure I can adequately answer questions 2-3. Question 1 seems mostly an academic exercise involving lots of `browser()` and `parent.frame()`, not sure it's helpful on its own.

Comment: +1 for answering my question number (4). It’s great to see that there is a way to make it work in base, although for now it’s just a workaround. However, that this works actually confuses me even more. `.rows` is just the captured expression `rows`. And this evaluated in `data` with the enclosing caller environment of `subset_base`. But why does this even work? :-)

Comment: Well, what `.rows` does is allow you to pass an already-`substitute`d object to the inner function, that's all, and I dislike it from a purist perspective. I agree, I wish there were a way to only conditionally call `substitute` with the risk of calling it on an object of class `language`.